# No place to put device_admin.xml

Tags: android, xml, device-admin

I know that device_admin.xml should be put in my /res/xml folder but I have not a xml folder under the res folder. Where should I put it?

device_admin.xml:

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-policies>
    <limit-password/>

    <watch-login/>
</uses-policies>
```

Here is my screen shot:

[image]

EDIT: 
I am new so I could not add the xml folder. Please tell me what can I do here. (I right clicked on res folder)
[image]

Comment: xml folder is created by developer. It does not appear by default

Comment: You could create it?

Comment: @Shahzeb I edited my question

Comment: Select 'Directory' -> name it 'xml'

Comment: select `Android Resource directory`

Comment: create new folder named xml in res.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android studio can do that for you:

1. Add the link in the Manifest:

`<meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin" android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />`

2. The studio will write it in red as it has no such resource. Then just click at it and press `Alt+Enter`. The first option will be to create such resource file.

Answer (score 2):

**Steps -**
1) Go to the place where your Project is located in Windows Explorer.
2) Then open the Module in which you want to add `device-admin.xml`.
3) Go to `res` folder and create a folder named `xml` inside that folder.
4) Refresh (or Synchronize, keyboard Shortcut -`ctrl + alt + Y`) the project in Android Studio.
5) Put `device-admin.xml` in the folder in Studio. 
**Alternate option -**

Right-Click the module > New > Directory > Enter name `xml` and select Resource type - `xml`.

Comment: Thanks for +1. **PS -** Mark it as selected answer too :)